# Columnstore index vs replication

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am investigating a new SQL Server 2012/2014 DB that we will be using to migrate data from a legacy Postgres DB. The data will be used both by a web application and for reporting purposes.

One of the key problems that we need to address is the performance of many reports [data sizes increasing from 1 - 50 million records].

In line with ["best practice"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727264/statistics-on-large-table-presented-on-the-web) we initially thought of implementing a separate reporting DB, which we had assumed would be populated by REPLICATION.

At the same time, I had a look at using [COLUMNSTORE index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088(v=sql.120).aspx), because our data is predominantly read-only. We have a period between April-June during which data is inserted, and then for the remainder of the year the data is not modified. But the peak period of OLTP data entry, is also the peak period for OLAP reporting needs, which is the reason for separating the two databases.

The issue we are having to resolve is that COLUMNSTORE indexes cannot be used with REPLICATION.

The alternatives seem to be

- initially use a single DB for both OLTP and OLAP, implementing COLUMNSTORE indexes and monitoring performance. If we use SQLServer 2014 we could then also make full use of CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE indexes which are updateable.
- create reporting DB from the start and use SSIS (or some form of ETL process) to transfer the data to the reporting DB. Implement COLUMNSTORE indexes for worst reports.

I'd appreciate any feedback based on experience of other projects.

Comment: You might want to look also SQL Server 2016

Comment: What does 2016 offer? It might not be an option due to corporate licensing

Comment: Curious as to why columnstore isn't an option with replication. There's nothing saying that the publisher and subscriber schema have to match (specifically with respect to indexing).

Comment: Columnstore MSDN docs don't explain reason. Maybe has to do with paging of  column index segments and rowgroups?

Answer (score 4):

Just found this question and so decided to comment on it - in SQL Server 2016 you can use replication with updatable Nonclustered Columnstore Index on publisher, as well as on the Subscriber. 
There are even 2 new options for activating direct replication of the Nonclustered Columnstore Index (default & filtered). More details can be found here:
[Columnstore Indexes – part 83 (“Columnstore Replication in SQL Server 2016”)](http://www.nikoport.com/2016/05/29/columnstore-indexes-part-83-columnstore-replication-in-sql-server-2016/)
Clustered Columnstore is not supported so far, which is of course a great pity for any DWH scenario.